# Merging OR conditions in EL

Tags: jsf, el

Is it possible to reduce this expression:

```
expanded="#{bean.item == 'item1' or bean.item == 'item2' or bean.item == 'item3'}"
```

to something like

```
bean.item == {'item1', 'item2', 'item3'}
```

in EL?

Comment: If checking for `item` only is good enough something like this can be used `expanded="#{bean.item.indexOf('item') ne -1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Closest what you can do is creating a custom EL function something like

```
expanded="#{my:isOneOf(bean.item, 'item1', 'item2', 'item3')}"
```

But since EL functions doesn't support varargs, you'd need to create a new method for every amount of arguments you need. An alternative is to offer explicit (and documented!) support for a delimited string, e.g. comma separated:

```
expanded="#{my:isOneOf(bean.item, 'item1,item2,item3')}"
```